# Binding BarBackgroundColorProperty in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm relatively new to C# and the idea of data binding (that is, I'm not sure I completely understand it). I am looking to try to bind NavigationPage's BarBackgroundColorProperty for sake of being able to change my root page's bar background color multiple times for a theme feature I'm trying to implement. I've searched around for examples of binding this property and haven't had much luck. Could someone point me in the right direction? If anything is unclear, please let me know. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an instance of NavigationPage called `myBindingPage` and a view model that extends [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) called `myViewModel` that has a property called `BarBgColor`, you should be able to set up a binding like this:

```
myBindingPage.SetBinding(NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColorProperty, new Binding("BarBgColor"));
```

N.B. I haven't actually tried this, but the [API doc](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.NavigationPage) does list [BarBackgroundColor](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=F%3AXamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColorProperty) as a bindable property.

Comment: I did eventually get this working, this was exactly the push I needed, thank you. :)